# Enviar form sem fechar modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma pagina com oportunidades de trabalho, quando clico em um botão[image: img1] ele chama um modal e exibe um formulário[image: img2] onde ao enviar as informações preciso que ele não recarregue a página e exiba uma msg de confirmação.

O que vem acontecendo é que depois de enviado, ele fecha o modal e se eu clicar no botão para cadastrar ele carrega a mensagem de enviado.
[image: img3]

Estou tentando usar Ajax, mas não estou tendo sucesso!

```
$("#form1").submit(function(event){    
      // event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //En

    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        type: request_method,
        data : form_data
    }).done(function(response){ 
       alert('acabou');
    });
});
```

Comment: Esse formulário já está enviando o cadastro com Ajax ou está recarregando a página?

Comment: Ele envia o cadastro e recarrega.. Se eu usar event.preventDefault() ele não deixa mais eu postar. O meu botão utiliza type submit.. não se se influência.

Comment: Ah sim, tem na pergunta dizendo que recarrega, eu não vi direito. Bom, então no caso vc converter para Ajax.

Comment: Acho que seria interessante você postar o código HTML de sua página, precisamos saber como funciona seu modal e quais bibliotecas você está utilizando.

Comment: Thales, estou trabalhando com um cms, ele cria tudo meio que automático. Só consigo manipular javascript... esse está sendo minha dificuldade.

Comment: Sam, Quando o form é preenchido e enviado, preciso que ele me de a msg de enviado em seguida.. mas ele fecha o modal sem exibir. Se eu vou no botão da primeira página(candidatar a vaga), ele abre o modal com a msg

Comment: Vc desabilitou o `event.preventDefault();`... ele que vai impedir o recarregamento da página.

Comment: Se eu ativo ele, não consigo enviar. O botão não envia.

Comment: esse é o meu form <form name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/oportunidades.aspx" id="form1">

Comment: Não, o preventDefault apenas irá cancelar o submit, mas o Ajax que vem depois será processado normalmente.

Comment: Coloquei um alerta, quando to com o preventDefault , ele não exibe nada. Sem ele me mostra o alerta.

Comment: Olha no console se mostra algum erro. A página para onde estão sendo enviados os dados pode não estar preparada para receber dados via Ajax, pode ter redirecionamentos etc...

Comment: Como vc disse que não consegue alterar páginas, somente o JS, então creio que não há o que fazer no seu caso. Para enviar dados via Ajax, a página destino deve conter apenas os códigos que irão tratar os dados, não pode ser uma página comum.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` previne o comportamento normal do form que é `submit`.

Answer (score 0):

**Formulário**

```
<form id="formUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" />

    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

    <input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" />
</form>

<button onclick="enviar();">enviar</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function enviar() {

    var data = new FormData($('#formUpload')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        method: 'post',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success === true) {
                ShowMessageSuccess('envie seu corriculo', result.MsgReturn);
            } else {
                ShowMessageError('envie seu corriculo', result.MsgReturn);
            }
        },
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult enviar(BaseHourViewModel form, HttpPostedFileBase file){
     //Código
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Um motivo pelo qual o modal é fechado, pode ser pela submissão do formulário.

Para evitar existem duas formas:

**Utilizando return false**

```
$("#form1").submit(function(event){    
      // event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //En

    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        type: request_method,
        data : form_data
    }).done(function(response){ 
       alert('acabou');
    });

    return false; // evitando recarregamento do form
});
```

**Ou utilizando preventDefault**

```js
$("#form1").submit(function(event){    
      // event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //En

    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        type: request_method,
        data : form_data
    }).done(function(response){ 
       alert('acabou');
    });

    event.preventDefault(); // evitando recarregamento do form
});
```

Eu particularmente costumo utilizar o **return false**.

Se mesmo assim o modal continuar fechando, o código do modal precisa ser verificado.

Isso acontece pois por padrão o envio do formulário é feito na própria janela, como neste caso é feito via ajax, o recarregamento não deve ocorrer.

Answer (score 0):

Tente alterar o tipo do botão de submit para button.
Exemplo:

```
$('input').prop('type','button');
```

No entanto após isso você não conseguirá pegar o evento submit, mas poderia mapear pegando o click do botão.

```
$("#botao").click(function(event){    
    // event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //En

    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        type: request_method,
        data : form_data
    }).done(function(response){ 
       alert('acabou');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -4):

Use o ajaxForm.
Ex: 
$('#nome_form').ajaxForm(function(){
  //mensagem depois do envio..
});